# Thumb up/down satisfaction emoji UI on bot framework composer with adaptative card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

Going through the issues page of bot framework composer, I stumbled on this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/4773#issuecomment-731111648) which shows an interesting UI card for getting the user's satisfactory :

[image]

Does this looks like an adaptive card ? How can we reproduce that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest thing to do is go to the designer on [Adaptivecards.io](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/). They have a super simple Adaptive Cards Designer experience that is drag and drop.

on other tabs they have example templates which you can launch in the designer to see how they work and play with them.

In your example above, the card is simply a text field with two image links and the images are clickable.
You can use the containers and/or columns components in the designer to layout the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hero card to get user satisfaction response by using thumbs up/thumbs down emoji.

```
[Herocard
    text = Are you satisfied?
    buttons =  | 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following JSON is a sample for thumbs up and down input choice

```
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Do you like the product"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "style": "expanded",
            "isMultiSelect": false,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "value": "yes"
                },
                {
                    "title": "",
                    "value": "no"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
            "spacing": "None"
        },
```