# How to customize hero card in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I am just thinking could I see what would be the options to prototype 'feedback' from the user after each response in my chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework using C#.

It is just like a "thumbs up/down" buttons after each response. I am not sure whether i can do it in c# using Microsoft Bot Framework but if the bot always accepted UP/DOWN as a potential feedback, I could store it somewhere next to the response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thumb up/down satisfaction emoji UI on bot framework composer with adaptative card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240525/thumb-up-down-satisfaction-emoji-ui-on-bot-framework-composer-with-adaptative-ca)

Comment: you can make use of the templates in the Adaptive card [designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)